# getting error in react native android sync >> Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.3

Tags: react-native

Gradle sync failed and log stated that not able to find `https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/common/23.2.0/common-23.2.0-javadoc.jar`
The problem was related to node_module react-native-prompt-android

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but with `react-native-image-picker`.
I've edited `node_module/react-native-image-picker/android/build.gradle` to use `3.1.4` gradle version. After that i got an other error. So i've added `google()` in repositories. Then, i asked to AndroidStudo to sync project with gradle files. All seems working good. Hope that will help.

Edit: I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/999#issuecomment-445465847) which describe what i did to solve this issue (on react-native-image-picker)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3` to `3.1.2` in build.gradle inside `node_modules/react-native-prompt-android/android/app/build.gradle`